# Having problems printing a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, filereader

Write a program that reads a student’s name together with his or her test score from a file given by the user.

The first two values in the file will represent the number of students followed by the number of tests. The program should then compute the average test score for each student and assign the appropriate grade (`A, B, C, D, E or F`) as well as the average of each test.

**External file**

```
tom 91 67 84 50 69
suzy 74 78 58 62 64
Peter 55 95 81 77 61
Paul 91 95 92 77 86
Diane 91 54 52 53 92
Emily 82 71 66 68 95
Natalie 97 76 71 88 69
Ben 62 67 99 85 94
Mark 53 61 72 83 73
Anna 64 91 61 53 68
```

Based off of the example my teacher gave us I have been trying to get it to print the list in a 2D array.

```
 private static final String FILENAME = "/Users/Kal-El/Documents/Programming/grades.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //below code to read from a file
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;
        String students [] = new String[10];
        int [][] grades = new int [10][5];

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            students = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

            for (int i=0; i < students.length; i++){
                for (int j=0; j < grades.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(grades[i][j]+" ");

                } // end of inner for loop

            } //end of outer for loop

        } // end of while loop

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } // end of catch

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Hint: You need to parse and set the `grades`, you aren't currently.

Comment: sCurrentLine.split(" ") will return the students and grades yo should use
sCurrentLine.split(" ")[0] to get the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `currentLine.split(" ")` will return the entire line broken up by spaces. So the line

```
tom 91 67 84 50 69
```

will turn into this array:

```
["tom", "91", "67", "84", "50", "69"]
```

So looping over it like this

```
for (int i=0; i < students.length; i++)
```

is not looping over all the students, it's looping over one student's name and all their scores. The very first item in the array will be the student's name so you can output that by doing `System.out.print(students[0])`.

You can loop over the scores for that student by doing this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < students.length; i++)
```

Sum them up as you do that to get the average. I'm not sure what your concept for the `grades` array of arrays was, but I don't think you need it.